# Handle request from external website

Tags: java, http, playframework, twitter

I'm writing an application that sends requests to the Twitter API. One part of the flow requires a redirect to the Twitter login page. After the user has logged in, a request is sent back to the callback url with information I need to continue the flow. The thing is, after logging in, my application pops up with the relevant information in the url bar. So, for example the url would look like this:

{http://localhost:9000/?oauth_token=KlQrT7YoFC2j3wAVGK57JRRI5h6LFI08H1zkhm8uEo&oauth_verifier=dU1H8D1no1wmKNRdpecHDrWegTQm4dvI15rnUblqxM}

I need the information after the {'http://localhost:9000'} so my question is, how do I get that?

The only information I can find on HTTP Request is making them, very little about receiving them. And even the stuff I did find on receiving them doesn't cover the issue I'm having. I imagine a solution to this problem could be very useful seeing as it goes to the core of any application that wants to implement sign in with Twitter.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a controller which serves /, example `routes` file

```
GET     /                                        Twitter.authorize
```

And then in the controller you can use the parameters:

```
public static void authorize(String oauth_token, String oauth_verifier) {
  .... do something ....
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please flag the question as accepted answer if it helped you.